# Defining classes using Allegro in XCODE

Tags: xcode, class, allegro5

Hi I have managed to get Allegro working within XCODE 5.1.1. I am working through the tutorials and examples and have come across this error when defining the class:

[image: Screen shot of class and error]

Can anyone help? The writing is not purple as should be either, have I missed a vital include file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem on a post here https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/613728 I needed to create the file as C++ and not C as I had done. This fixed it.